# Chess: knight move diagram with 'L' shaped arrows

Tags: chess, chessboard

When drawing knight moves in a board, is it possible to make the line look like an 'L', ie straight for 2 squares then turning 90 degrees and straight again?

For example, the following piece of code

```
\chessboard[setwhite={Nd4},
 pgfstyle=knightmove,
 markmoves={d4-b5, d4-c6, d4-e6, d4-f5, d4-f3, d4-e2, d4-c2, d4-b3},
 showmover=false]
```

but with every arrow looking like this

```
\chessboard[setwhite={Nd4},
 pgfstyle=knightmove,
 markmoves={d4-b4, b4-b5},
 showmover=false]
```

where the lines touch of course and there's only one arrow.

Comment: Which package do you talk about?

Comment: @MS-SPO I am currently using chessboard and xskak but I am flexible with packages.

Comment: you can define your own drawing styles.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer You mean via the bezier curve?

Comment: @cgss: Which one ?? https://www.ctan.org/topic/games ... That's why posting a MWE is helpful: you'd mentioned the exact package there ...

Comment: @cgss: Just wondering ... if it's this package https://mirror.marwan.ma/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/chessboard/chessboard.pdf, did you read the manual  e.g. p. 49 ?

Comment: @MS-SPO Yes. See my comment just above. The bezier curve mentioned is used within the curvemove style in page 50 of the same document.

Comment: you don't need a bezier curve for a L, only straight moves, but you need to define a new drawing style.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The drawing is basically a set of pgf commands. You can copy such a style and change it or use it to define your own styles:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chessboard}
\makeatletter
\cbDefinePgfMoveStyle{knightmove|-}{%
   \pgfsetlinewidth{\board@pgf@linewidth}%
   \pgfsetarrowsend{\board@pgf@arrow}%
   \setlength\len@board@tempx{\dimexpr 0.3em + \board@pgf@shortenstart \relax}%
   \pgfsetshortenstart{\len@board@tempx}%
   \setlength\len@board@tempx{\board@pgf@shortenend}%
   \pgfsetshortenend{\len@board@tempx}%
   \pgfextractx{\len@board@tempx}{\pgfpointanchor{#1}{center}}%
   \pgfextracty{\len@board@tempy}{\pgfpointanchor{#1}{center}}%
   \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointorigin}%
   \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{0pt}{\len@board@tempy}}%
   \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointanchor{#1}{center}}%
   \pgfusepath{stroke}}%
\cbDefinePgfMoveStyle{knightmove-|}{%
   \pgfsetlinewidth{\board@pgf@linewidth}%
   \pgfsetarrowsend{\board@pgf@arrow}%
   \setlength\len@board@tempx{\dimexpr 0.3em + \board@pgf@shortenstart \relax}%
   \pgfsetshortenstart{\len@board@tempx}%
   \setlength\len@board@tempx{\board@pgf@shortenend}%
   \pgfsetshortenend{\len@board@tempx}%
   \pgfextractx{\len@board@tempx}{\pgfpointanchor{#1}{center}}%
   \pgfextracty{\len@board@tempy}{\pgfpointanchor{#1}{center}}%
   \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointorigin}%
   \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\len@board@tempx}{0pt}}%
   \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointanchor{#1}{center}}%
   \pgfusepath{stroke}}% 
\makeatother     
\begin{document}
\chessboard[setwhite={Nd4},
 pgfstyle=knightmove|-,
 markmoves={d4-b5, d4-c6, d4-e6, d4-f5, d4-f3, d4-e2, d4-c2, d4-b3},
 showmover=false] 

\chessboard[setwhite={Nd4},
 pgfstyle=knightmove-|,
 markmoves={d4-b5, d4-c6, d4-e6, d4-f5, d4-f3, d4-e2, d4-c2, d4-b3},
 showmover=false]
 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Just for clarification in case it is something advanced that I am not aware of, but is your second `\makeatletter` meant to be `\makeatother` or is that intended?

Comment: @JamesT I have a 50% chance to get this wrong when typing fast ;-)